# How to calculate the Ra and Rb values for the desired frequency and duty cycle?

Tags: 555, duty-cycle

I am designing a DC-DC boost converter for Vin = 5V to Vout = 15V. To generate gate pulses, I will be using a NE555P Timer by TI - http://pdf1.alldatasheet.com/datasheet-pdf/view/161277/TI/NE555P.html. For astable operation, from the data sheet I realised the following data [Pg-7]:

Frequency (f) = 10 KHz,
Capacitance (C) = 0.1uF,
Ra + 2Rb = 1K,
Duty Cycle (D) = 1 - (Vin/Vout)
               = 0.66 or 66.6%,

Priod = th + tl = 0.1ms,

Now, how do I calculate the resistance values of Ra and Rb for the desired duty cycle?. And what is the difference between **Output driver duty cycle** and **Output waveform duty cycle**?. Which one of these formulae can I use to find Ra and Rb satisfying Ra + 2Rb = 1K?

```
              //Some Calculations I did until now to find Ra and Rb//
```

D = Rb/(Ra+2Rb)),
0.66 = Rb/1K,
Rb = 660 ohms,

Ra + 2Rb = 1K,
Ra + 2(660) = 1K,
Ra = 1000 - 1320,
Ra = -0.32K????-----------> Getting a Wrong value since it should not come negative!!,

```
                     //My next try to calculate Ra and Rb//
```

D = 1-(Rb/(Ra+2Rb)),
0.66 = 1-(Rb/1K),
Rb = 340 ohms,

Ra+2Rb = 1k,
Ra+2(340) = 1K,
Ra = 320 ohms,

So, 320 +2(340) = 1000, satisfies Ra + 2Rb = 1K( But not getting 66% duty cycle).

So which one is correct? or my approach and understanding itself to finding the values of Ra and Rb is wrong?. Please help.

Comment: The difference is that the output amplifier is inverting, therefore its duty cycle is 1 - the astable duty cycle. Use whichever equation is physically realisable, and if necessary, add an inverter after the output to get the waveform you need.

Comment: Are you saying that, D = 1-0.66, so the output duty cycle I see on the oscilloscope is actually 34% (ON) and not 66% (ON)?. So, to get the 66% duty cycle I need to use an inverter at the output at any case?

Comment: Yes, with the standard application schematic, the smallest dutycycle you can get is just below 50%. This is because charging uses Ra + Rb but discharging only Rb. Therefore discharging always takes less time and ducy < 50%! You can work around that as you said with an inverter but there is another trick using a diode, see: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/57226/555-timer-in-astable-mode-how-can-i-achieve-longer-low-output-than-high

The diode takes care Ra is for charging only and Rb for discharing only, solving your problem !